# How would intergalactic time delay work with bitcoin blockchain syncing correctly?

Tags: block-propagation-time, transaction-propagation

The year is 2097, we just colonized mars. Sending any type of data from Earth to Mars takes about 10 minutes.

If I made a transaction on mars sending some bitcoins to someone on earth, it would take at least 10 minutes for it to propagate to all the nodes on Earth. During this time gap, I make a double spend transaction on Earth to send to mars. Because the nodes on Earth hasn't gotten my updated balance from the transaction on mars. What happens?

Does this cause a fork in the bitcoin blockchain due to this large delay? What if the time gap is 1 hour or even a few days, say sending a message to a colony on pluto? How does the bitcoin blockchain solve this problem?